# Loading Json as Column Type using Arquillian and Wildfly setup

Tags: java, json, postgresql, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to load json to json Column type in Postgresql by using Arquillian and Wildfly Server. So basically I have Written an InContainer Test.

```
@Test
@UsingDataSet("datasets/contracts/contracts.yml")

public void FindContractByContractCodeAndUserId_ValidContractResponse() {

    ContractResponse contractResponse = contractBoundary.getContractByContractCodeAndUserId("0816QMCG", 1);
    assertThat(contractResponse, notNullValue());
    assertThat(contractResponse.getAmount(), is(800.0));
    assertThat(contractResponse.getDescription(), is("MacBook"));
    assertThat(contractResponse.getImageLink(), is("http://dasdas.de/"));
    assertThat(contractResponse.isShowOnMarketplace(), is(false));
    assertThat(contractResponse.getStatus(), is(ContractStatusEnum.PENDING));
}
```

The yml file is contains a column which is json type, something like below:

data: {"data":{"newAmount":700.23}}

The application it self can store json type in postgresql.

Now I am writing an InContainer test that will loads data to an in-memory database H2, but I checked out the H2 doesn't support json so I Moved to using postgresql and deployed the psql driver, but when I am running tests, I always get the following error:

java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.dbunit.dataset.NoSuchColumnException: contract_events.DATA - (Non-uppercase input column: data) in ColumnNameToIndexes cache map. Note that the map's column names are NOT case sensitive. at org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData.getColumnIndex(AbstractTableMetaData.java:117) at

And the Test fails to seed the database.  !!!!

Answer (score 0):

This means that DBUnit which is used under the hood cannot find column named `DATA`. Are you using proper data type factory for dbunit? For Arquillian Persistence Extension you can configure it in `arquillian.xml` as follows:

```
<extension qualifier="persistence-dbunit">
    <property name="datatypeFactory">org.dbunit.ext.postgresql.PostgresqlDataTypeFactory</property>
</extension>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this didn't help, as I understand this enables  arquillian (db unit under hood) to basically to use postgresql data type. The column that I am seeding is a json type. Could it be possible to say that dbUnit doesn't support json type for seeding purpose. ? Rest if there is a work around for this that will be great.

Comment: If you could share the project on GH I could hack around, send PR and comment here for the others :)

Comment: [PostgresqlDataTypeFactory](https://sourceforge.net/p/dbunit/code.git/ci/master/tree/dbunit/src/main/java/org/dbunit/ext/postgresql/PostgresqlDataTypeFactory.java) doesn't support `json` or `jsonb` types. See source code for list of extra supported types.